# Swipe Left or Right in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swipe, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a page that retrieves data from the database to display info about the current info or previous or after

It goes that

```
if Status = 1 it shows the current
Status = 2 it shows previous
Status = 0 it shows next
```

What I did so far is display the current data and it shows perfectly
I need to do a feature that when the user swipes right to left shows next
and left to right shows previous

Any Idea or guideline just from where to start

Thank you

Comment: You said, "What I did so far is display the current data and it shows perfectly" are you showing the data on a view controller ?

Comment: check this link http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/detecting-swipe-gesture-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: @iamyogish Yes the data is showing on a view controller

Comment: Then you could use UIPageViewController to achieve what you want.

Comment: @iamyogish will look into that ! thank you

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose Thanks for the tutorial!

Answer (score 12):

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()

let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

}


func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer
    {
        switch swipeGesture.direction
        {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                 //write your logic for right swipe
                  print("Swiped right")

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                 //write your logic for left swipe
                  print("Swiped left")

            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the example code above you could just use one gesture recognizer and set the direction as follows `swipeRight.direction = [UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left, UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right]`

Comment: I recieve signal SIGABRT :(

Answer (score -1):

```
class WelcomeController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Create left swipe gesture recognizer
        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(_:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        
        // Create right swipe gesture recognizer
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(_:)))
        rightSwipe.direction = .right
        backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
        
    }
    
    @objc func handleSwipe(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer.direction == .left {
            // Handle left swipe
        } else if gestureRecognizer.direction == .right {
            // Handle right swipe
        }
    }
}

// Use ChatGPT
```